# Get records that has some value in some tandem period

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Please consider this table:

```
Id    City     Year     Month    F1    F2
-----------------------------------------
1    London    2012     1       10     05
2    London    2012     2       10     05
3    London    2012     3       10     05
4    Paris     2012     1       10     05
5    Paris     2012     2       10     06
6    Tokyo     2013     7       10     05
7    Tokyo     2013     8       10     05
8    Moscow    2013     1       10     05
9    Moscow    2013     3       10     05
```

I want records that `F2 = '05'` for **two** tandem periods(Year-Month). For example for above data I want this result:

```
Id    City     Year     Month    F1    F2
-----------------------------------------
1    London    2012     1       10     05
2    London    2012     2       10     05
6    Tokyo     2013     7       10     05
```

every above row has a record with `F2 = '05'` in it's next period(Year-Month). How I can get this result?

Thanks

Comment: Improve the sample data with a December-January tandem period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.id, a.city, a.year, a.month, a.f1, a.f2
FROM mytable a, mytable b
WHERE ((b.month = a.month + 1 AND b.year = a.year) 
 OR (b.year = a.year + 1 AND a.month = 12 AND b.month = 1))
AND a.city = b.city AND b.f2 = '05';
```

Comment: Thanks it works.but Can you show me If I want 3 tandem periods What can I do?

Comment: Same idea, except you'll be joining three copies of mytable.